# How convert string (masked) to decimal?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, maskedtextbox

I have mask in textbox "99:99" I need convert to decimal.
example: string "12:34" converted to 12.34

I create method:

```
private decimal ConvertStringMaskToDecimal(string strMask)
{
    var split = strMask.Split(':');
    if(split.Length==2)
    {
        decimal returnValue = decimal.Parse(split[0]) + decimal.Parse(split[1])/100;
        return returnValue;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("strMask not valid");
    }
}
```

this code is worked but I think the code is not correct, how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `:` with `.` before parsing:

```
decimal.Parse(strMask.Replace(':', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Note the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to ensure that the `.` is interpreted correctly.

Comment: Hardcoding a dot as a decimal separator is not a good practice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg

Comment: @Konrad Morawski, how do this?

Answer (score 3):

As I remarked in my comment to Oded's answer: hardcoding a dot as a decimal separator is not recommended.

[This picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDecimalSeparator.svg) explains why.

I suggest:

```
using System.Globalization;

// (...)
decimal.Parse(strMask.Replace(":", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));
```

instead.

Or, as Henk Holterman suggested:

```
decimal.Parse(strMask.Replace(':', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To the same effect (not crashing on non-American machines).

Comment: Might as well use:  `decimal.Parse(..., CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @HenkHolterman you're right. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `decimal.Parse` after replacing colon `:` with the decimal point `.`

```
decimal.Parse(strMask.Replace(':', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```